# Sample size to distinguish Bernoulli from Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, concentration-of-measure

I would like to address the following question. How many samples is required to distinguish between a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $1/2 - \epsilon$ and a uniform distribution over $\{0, 1\}$. I know that this statement is not mathematically rigorous, so I'm looking to answer two questions:

1. How can I rephrase the statement to be mathematically rigorous?
2. I feel like somehow concentration measures (like Hoeffding's inequality) may help to answer the question, but don't know how, any idea?

Comment: By "uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}$" do you mean the Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\frac12$ or the continuous uniform distribution over the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Math1000 I mean the Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.